# Getting the DOM element that caused a request to be sent

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there any way from an `nsIChannel`/`nsIStreamListener` to get the HTML element that caused the request to be sent in the first place?

I subscribed to `http-on-examine-response` and I am using `nsITraceableChannel.setNewListener` to read and modify incoming content. I want to only modify javascript content loaded from `script` tags, but I haven't found a reliable way to identify which responses are suitable. The MIME header cannot be trusted. Can I access information about what FF is planning to use this request for?

Perhaps something to do with the callbacks or the observers in the loadgroup?

Edit:
is the aContentType argument of nsIContentPolicy.shouldLoad trustworthy? If I was able to pass information through the channel, I'd be set...

Answer (score 0):

> is the aContentType argument of nsIContentPolicy.shouldLoad trustworthy?

AFAIK, yes, as far as core code is involved, but expect add-ons to misbehave.

The [nsScriptLoader](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/base/src/nsScriptLoader.cpp#214) implementation will check it before loading an external script. Other core code does not (ab)use the same type. But keep in mind that you won't be notified asked inline scripts. Also, `aContext` to `shouldLoad` should be an `nsIScriptElement` (non-scriptable) in case of scripts, which is also an nsIScriptLoaderObserver (scriptable) and might be a `nsIDOMHTMLScriptElement`, so I guess you could `QI/instanceof` the `aContext` just to make sure.

As for getting the element from an `nsIChannel` via http-observers: I don't think that it is possible to do so. The script element I mentioned above will be stuffed into a non-scriptable `nsScriptLoadRequest`, which in turn is supplied as a context to `nsIChannel.asyncOpen()`, so it isn't available even if it was scriptable.